# jQuery: How to trigger a callback function after `animate()` function completes

Tags: jquery

I would like to be able to use a callback in a stack of events, but not at the end. I tried to do it, but it seems the code escapes any effects after the callback has been called.

```
$(this).animate({//animate image
                top:0
            }, aniTime)

            .delay(1000, function(){

             //some code

            })

            .animate({//animate image
                top:250
            }, aniTime)
```

Is there a way to do this or is it not possible/best practise ?

Comment: I do not understand this quesion

Comment: So you want to animate top to 0, wait 1000ms, then animate top to 250?

Comment: There is a delay until the next animation, but want to fade some other selector in the callback. That make sense? I know I can do it outside the scope, but was wondering if it's possible to keep the code neater

Comment: So you want to fade another element out after the delay?
jQuery `delay()` does not accept callbacks as arguments.
https://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: Yeah. So that is executes the same time as the final animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this effect by using the `complete` callback parameter of animate. This will run it's contents on completion of the first animate at the same time as the delay time begins.

Example:

```
$(this).animate({//animate image
        top:0
    }, aniTime,
    // complete callback follows:
    function(){
        $('otherElement').fadeOut(200);
    })
    .delay(1000)
    .animate({//animate image
        top:250
    }, aniTime)
```